# Edge states in the "half BHZ" model

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

Consider the "half BHZ" Hamiltonian

$${\cal H}=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(A\sin(k_{x})\sigma_{x}+A\sin(k_{y})\sigma_{y}+{\cal M}(\mathbf{k})\sigma_{z}\right)c_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}c_{\mathbf{k}}$$ where $M(\mathbf{k})=M-2B\left(2-\cos(k_{x})-\cos(k_{y})\right)$

For simplicity, take A=1 and B > 0. M < 0 and M > 8B give a trivial phase, while 0 < M < 4B and 4B < M < 8B give topological phases with Chern number $\pm1$ and the corresponding edge states. The existence of the edge states can be easily verified by numerically diagonalizing the Hamiltonian for periodic boundary conditions in, say, the x direction and vanishing boundary conditions in the y direction. They can also be found analytically by expanding the Hamiltonian around the TRIM points $(k_x, k_y) = (0, 0), (0, \pi), (\pi, 0), (\pi, \pi)$ to second order and looking for solutions localized near a boundary. The trouble is, the expansion around $(0,0)$ seems to imply that the only condition for the existence of a localized state at $k_x=E=0$ is MB > 0. But we know that for M > 4B there's no such state, so what happens to it? I think it's supposed to somehow pair-annihilate with the $(0, \pi)$ edge state when M becomes bigger than 4B, but according to the expansion around $(0, \pi)$ the $(0, \pi)$ edge state vanishes on its own. Is there some other explanation for the disappearance of the $(0, 0)$ edge state? Or does it annihilate with the $(0, \pi)$ edge state after all, but there's no way to see it from the local Hamiltonians?

Comment: For reference this is the Qi-Wu-Zhang model. Bernevig Hughes and Zhang studied two glued together into a TI with time reversal symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. However, I would rephrase what you said to a technically more accurate form: the **band inversions** at $\mathbf{k} = (0, \; 0)$ and $\mathbf{k} = (0, \; \pi)$ annihilate each other at $M = 4B$. I am strictly following the formalism of Fu and Kane (since the BHZ model has inversion symmetry):

> Liang Fu and Charles L. Kane. “[Topological insulators with inversion symmetry](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.76.045302).” *Physical Review B* **76**, no. 4 (2007): 045302. ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0611341))

You can define a quantity called the time-reversal polarization at the Time-Reversal Invariant Momentum (TRIM) values ($\Lambda_{a}$) on the edge (surface) Brillouin Zone (BZ) of a 2D (3D) topological insulator (Eq. (2.6)): $$\pi_{a} = \delta_{a1}\delta_{a2}$$ where $\delta_{i}$ is defined in Eq. (3.10) in terms of the band parities $\xi_{2n}$ $$\delta_{i}=\prod_{m=1}^{N}\xi_{2m}(\Gamma_{i})$$ The $\pi$’s are basically the projection of the $\delta$’s in the bulk BZ onto the surface BZ (see Fig. 1 (b) and (d)) at the TRIMs.

In the BHZ model, we only have two $\pi$’s: at $k_{x} = 0$ and $k_{x} = \pi$. When $M$ rises above $0$ the gap closes at $\mathbf{k} = (0, \; 0)$ and the bands invert (**only** at $\mathbf{k} = (0, \; 0)$) and we get $\delta_{(0, \; 0)} = -1$ and $\pi_{k_{x} = 0} = -1$ (the rest are $+1$). Eq. (2.10) picks up an extra $(-1)$ and $\nu$ goes from $0$ to $1 \; {\rm mod} \; 2$; i.e. the system becomes topologically nontrivial. When $M$ rises above $4B$ the gap closes at two points: $\mathbf{k} = (\pi, \; 0)$ and $\mathbf{k} = (0, \; \pi)$, and we get $\delta_{(\pi, \; 0)} = -1$ and $\delta_{(0, \; \pi)} = -1$. Then we get $\pi_{k_{x} = 0} = (-1)^2 = +1$ and $\pi_{k_{x} = \pi} = -1$. Thus the intersection of edge states moves from $k_{x} = 0$ to $k_{x} = \pi$ when $M$ rises above $4B$.

So to answer your question: yes, there is no way to see changes in edge states from the local Hamiltonians. Recall that the phase transition at $M = 4B$, which is accompanied by the closing of a bulk gap, results in the rearrangement of the **entire** electronic system. The Fu and Kane analysis involves analysis (above) of the *entire* bulk bandstructure can capture edge state shift.

Comment: Is this extra formalism really necessary for the half BHZ model? The way I thought about it was, for M > 4B the contributions of $(0, 0)$ and $(0, \pi)$ to the Chern number cancel, so due to bulk-edge correspondence there shouldn't be an edge state at $k_x = 0$. Anyway, this doesn't quite answer the question since at it *is* at least partly possible to see changes in edge states from the local Hamiltonians. Expanding around $(0, 0)$ [$(0, \pi)$] one can see there's no localized solution for M < 0 [M > 4B] while there is one for M > 0 [M < 4B].

Comment: The Fu & Kane formalism is an *intuitive* description of the same thing as the “Chern-number-like” computation; Chern number of TIs is zero. Evaluating the topological invariant (or Chern-number-like quantity), by integrating over the **entire** BZ, is overkill compared to the Fu & Kane formalism. I referred to it (as opposed to other tricks) because it makes sense to talk about annihilation of *parities* in this context, **not** edge states. It doesn’t make sense to say “edge states at $(0, \; \pi)$ and $(0, \; 0)$ annihilate each other.” (continued)

Comment: There is no edge state at $(0, \; \pi)$; this is in the bulk BZ. Edge states by definition have $k_{y} = 0$. Also, what I was trying to say was that local Hamiltonians don’t guarantee to give you all the information on edge states; non-triviality of TIs in a **global** property.

Comment: Well, yes, "edge state at $(0, \pi)$" wasn't accurate. What I meant was a state with $k_x=0, Re(k_y)=\pi$ and some small $Im(k_y)$ which determines the localization length (actually, the state is a linear combination of a state with small $Im(k_y)$ and a state with a large $Im(k_y)$ such that the vanishing boundary condition is satisfied). The existence of this state can be seen both by analytically solving the local Hamiltonian and by numerically diagonalizing the full Hamiltonian; doing the latter one sees that for M close to 4B the wavefunction changes sign between each y site.
(continued)

Comment: Another claim I didn't make accurately is "the contributions [...] to the Chern number cancel, so due to bulk-edge correspondence there shouldn't be an edge state". The accurate version would be "the contributions to the Chern number cancel, so due to bulk-edge correspondence there should be the same number of left and right moving edge states on *each* edge". That is, a Hamiltonian with Chern number 0 can have edge states, but it's adiabatically connected to a Hamiltonian that doesn't. So the non-triviality of TIs is a global property, but by itself, the existence of edge states isn't.

Comment: This is not true: “So the non-triviality […] existence of edge states isn’t.” Existence of **topologically protected** edge states is necessarily a property of the bulk (i.e. global property). The main point I’m trying to make is that are two types of edge/surface states: trivial and non-trivial. The trivial ones were known for decades and their existence can be seen by local Hamiltonians. The novelty of the recent breakthrough was Kane realizing that there appears a new pair of edge states, in addition to the trivial ones, when the insulator transitions to a TI phase. (continued)

Comment: For example, Bi$_{1-x}$Sb$_{x}$ has 4 and 5 Dirac cones in the trivial and non-trivial regime (tuned by $x$) respectively. You can destroy the 4 trivial ones by changing surface *details*. But the last (fifth) one is a global property and cannot be destroyed.
BTW, send me an email next time (physmeso@gmail.com). Someone told me that filling up the comments section is frowned upon on this site.